# Using a Bluetooth Headset to send voice to a bluetooth Speaker (Android)

Tags: bluetooth, headset

this is quite a strange question, but hoping someone can help me out. Basically I was hoping to have a bluetooth headset send audio to bluetooth speakers - basically as a sort of "remote mic and speaker" setup.

I have bluetooth speakers and a bluetooth headset, but they will not sync to each other (as they are both accessories I assume). So I was hoping to get a cheap android phone to be the middle man.

Problem is I can't seem to get the Mic and "Speaker" to seperate, nor an app that supports audio straight through. My ideal setup is as follows:

Speech in (Bluetooth headset) --> Sent to Speaker (Phone) --> Output from Speaker (Bluetooth Speaker).

Can anyone suggest a way to do this in Android? Are there apps that support this?

Thanks for your help, anyone that can help! :-)